# How to create for each div in a while loop an ID and alert it with JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have  2 paragraphs coming from the database it work there is no issues with it. But I have added a button that when I click it will alert the ID of this current div which the button is present.

Now this is my table:

```
+--------+--------------------+
|   id   |      paragraph     |
|--------+--------------------+
|   1    | this is text 1     |
|   2    | another text       |
+-----------------------------+
```

My PHP and HTML code:

```
<?php
  $query = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM tests);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
  $post_id = $row['id'];
  $text = $row['paragraph'];
?>

<div id='text' class='<?php echo "$post_id";?>'>
  <p><?php echo "$text";?></p>
  <input type='button' value='Show id' id='show'>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

And now probably 2 paragraphs are generated but when I click at show button it will show only the 1 id even if I click at the second one:

This is my JQuery code:

```
$('#show').click(function(){
   var ids = $("#text").attr('class');
   alert(ids);
});
```

Comment: `id=""` attribute values are supposed to be unique

Comment: Is it possible to add two classes?

Comment: @DustinScott you can have as many `classes` as you like. To do so, simply separate them with a space. (eg `<div class="class1 class2"></div>`)

Comment: @DustinScott yes you can have multiple classes just make sure you put spaces between them just as Senju described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id=""` attribute values are supposed to be unique. do the other way around:

```
<div id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" class='text'>
    <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
    <input type='button' value='Show id' class='button'>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('.button').click(function(){
   var ids = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');
   alert(ids);
});
```

> Note: Stop using `mysql_` functions, instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Sample:

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM tests');
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$post_id = $row['id'];
$text = $row['paragraph'];
?>

<div id="post_<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
    <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
    <button type="button" class="button">Show</button>
</div>

<?php } ?>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.button').click(function(){
   var ids = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');
   alert(ids);
});
</script>
```

Very important point from Jeroen:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)

Comment: +1 For completeness you might want to add that ID's and classes cannot be just a number or start with a number.

Comment: Ah good point @jeroen, i always for get the start with number, post_id is a number.

Comment: Okay what about if I want to add that button inside another div would the code be like this: `var ids = $('.newdiv').parent('div').attr('id');`

Comment: @DustinScott if you're going to wrap the button with another div. you're going to go one level down, so the first parent is the wrapper, the second will be the main parent so `$('button').parent().parent().attr('id')`

Comment: @DustinScott not good, use `$('button').closest('.class_name_of_the_most_parent_div').attr('id');` instead

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pass the ID as a parameter?

```
<?php
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tests");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
  $post_id = $row['id'];
  $text = $row['paragraph'];
?>

<div id='text' class='<?php echo "$post_id";?>'>
  <p><?php echo "$text";?></p>
  <input type='button' value='Show id' id='show' onclick="showId(<?php echo $post_id; ?>);">
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Then your script could look like this:

```
function showId(theId){
    alert(theId);
}
```

Comment: because he as the class and id reversed on the div tag.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Yeah but if he passes the actual id from the database, then it will alert it.

Comment: That's true but it doesn't really tell him what his mistake was.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, that's true. I offered an alternative (some may say simpler) way of accomplishing the given task.

Answer (score 0):

this is hard to read

```
<?php
  $query = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM tests);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
  $post_id = $row['id'];
  $text = $row['paragraph'];
?>

<div id='text' class='<?php echo "$post_id";?>'>
  <p><?php echo "$text";?></p>
  <input type='button' value='Show id' id='show'>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Try something like this

```
<?php
  $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tests');
  while(false !== ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))): 
?>

<div class='text' id='post-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>
  <p><?php echo $row['paragraph']; ?></p>
  <input type='button' value='Show id' id='show'>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I don't see how the query worked without quotes.  Just to explain you can use the alternative syntax for the while, so instead of

```
<?php while(. .. ){  ?>
   <html></html>
<?php }  ?>
```

do

```
  <?php while(... ): ?>
     <html></html>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

When you have a lot of html ( this is a small example ) you can easily find the diffrence between  endif; endwhile; or endforeach;  then  }  }  or }

Answer (score 0):

where it says:

```
class='<?php echo "$post_id";?>'
```

when you're echoing a php variable, you dont put quotes around it:

```
class='<?php echo $post_id;?>'.
```